# How to extract beta coefficients for interaction effect in R?

Tags: r, regression, mixed-models, interaction, dummy-variable

I am examining the interaction between a continuous variable (bloodq) and a categorical variable with three levels (ER, RB, and WB). In order to see how the betas differ across tissue types, I would like to know the tissue-specific betas for all three tissue types. Output only shows betas for WB and RB, since ER is set as referent group. How could I extract beta for RB as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure I have totally understood your question, what I understood is that you are wondering why there is no "Bloodq*ER" interaction coefficient.

You give the answer in your question: ER is the reference level, and adding such an interaction term in the model would raise exact collinearity issues, as:
`Bloodq == Bloodq*ER + Bloodq*RB + Bloodq*WB` (where `ER == 1` if `Tissue == "ER"`, 0 otherwise etc.)

Thus, removing Bloodq from your model should make the Bloodq*ER coefficient appear.

For instance, try this:

```
n <- 100
df <- data.frame(s1 = runif(n), s2 = sample(factor(c("A", "B")), n, replace = TRUE), y = runif(n))
lm(y ~ s1 + s1:s2, data = df)
lm(y ~ s1:s2, data = df)
```

You can see that the first model has only the s1:s2B interaction while the second one has s1:s2A and s1:s2B.

Comment: I am not putting bloodq in my model, however, apart from the interaction. 

model <- lmer(y ~ bloodq*tissue + (1|sample), data = df)

Comment: You do implicitely put Bloodq in the model (as shows the presence of a beta parameter for Bloodq) : "The ‘\*’ operator denotes factor crossing: ‘a*b’ interpreted as ‘a+b+a:b’" (from ?formula). Use the ‘:’ operator for interactions only.

Comment: Wow, I'm in near disbelief. I have always thought and read that "*" was equivalent to ":". I just ran the same code with the operator substitution, and the results are quite different! I dread having to re-run ~100 models now. Your answer is painful, but solves this problem. Thanks for showing me the light.